# Iodine ion vs caesium ion size

Tags: everyday-chemistry, ions

An iodine ion is the larger of the two, but why if they have the same amount of electrons? Also, $\ce{Li}$ is larger than $\ce{Li+}$, don't more electrons mean larger radius?

Answer (score 2):

Iodine is having 53 electrons and cesium is having 55 electrons in general. Iodine ion can be made by adding or by removing electrons from it. Here you added two electrons to iodine and made it an iodine ion in which number of electrons of iodine ion became equal to the number of electrons of cesium but the composition of nucleus(number of protons) is different in both iodine ion and cesium ion. Obviously cesium is having more number of protons than iodine, so cesium nucleus can hold it's electrons more closer in cesium than iodine nucleus in an iodine ion which results in larger radius of iodine ion than cesium.. 
Same number of electrons doesn't mean that their radii are same. Same logic is applicable for lithium ion and lithium.. Lithium ion is having less electrons and more protons compared to lithium.. So radius of lithium is larger than radius of lithium ion